# Reusing another faculty's material

Tags: etiquette

Is it rude to ask another faculty member if you can reuse their slides, notes etc?  I am new to teaching in a 4-year college and I am not sure if I can even ask my new colleagues this question.  It pops up when they help me and add me to their course pages they have taught a previous semester.  I see that their material is good and prompted to ask if I can reuse them.

Comment: They might say no, but of course you can **ask**.

Answer (score 9):

The culture in different departments is different. I've been in departments where the expectation is that everyone develop their own teaching materials. I've also been in groups and departments where if you asked whether you can use someone else's material, the answer would be "of course".

In general, reusing someone's materials without their consent is poor style. But I would suggest to all young faculty that they ask older colleagues what the culture of the department is. If the answer is "Yes, of course we help each other", then if you want to reuse someone's materials, the right approach is to ask them whether they'd be willing to share their materials.

Answer (score 3):

> It pops up when they help me and add me to their course pages they have taught a previous semester.

If you're already getting this kind of help and access from a fellow teacher, then it sounds totally fair (and perhaps expected) to request using their other materials (slides, etc.). I find most of my colleagues fairly flattered when I want to borrow their materials -- less a "get your own" mentality, more "glad to help".

If you get to borrow materials, you'll undoubtedly find yourself altering and adjusting them to fit your particular needs. If you add to them in some way, be sure to offer the updated files to the original author. Then voila -- you're the one sharing that great thing!

However, be prepared for a "no" from some. That's fine, though, and you should decide in advance to not take it personally.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**: It depends on your University practices and regulations.

There are (at least) two questions to consider:

1. **Who owns the materials?** In some Universities, the teaching materials produced by academics as a part of their contract belong to University, so when you inherit a course from another academic, you also inherit the materials. In some Universities, materials remain the property of academics who created them, but you still can ask nicely.
2. **Can you teach with their materials?** Some courses are very standard, but some are based on specific expertise of particular staff. Some materials may be easy to reuse, and some really tailored to a particular teaching style of a  staff member. If the course ran well with these materials in hands of another staff member, can you also make it work for you? Simply saving your time on preparation may result in confusion during the class because you did not design these materials and don't know how to use them efficiently.